# Difference between {-# UNPACK #-} Type# in GHC Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

In GHC, what is the difference between the `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragma and the `#` type suffix operator?

For example, what is the difference between:

```
data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} Int
```

and

```
data T = T Int#
```

Comment: `Int#` isn't "`Int` with some unary operator `#` at the end". `Int#` is the name of a type, and doesn't _really_ have anything to do with `Int` (as far as the type system is concerned anyway).

Comment: Note you are missing an `!` before the `Int` for the `UNPACK` variant.

Comment: If I am reading the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#unpack-pragma) right, there is no difference between these.

Comment: @Cubic: fair enough. But in this case the type `Int#` is defined. Is there still any difference between `{-# UNPACK #-} !Int` and `Int#`? And is the general difference merely that `{-# UNPACK #-}` can be used with any type, whereas `Type#` can only be used with the limited list of types including `Int#`?

Comment: In general, however, `UNPACK` is more powerful as it can flatten more complex data structures automatically.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, from [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html):

> The `UNPACK` indicates to the compiler that it should unpack the
>   contents of a constructor field into the constructor itself, removing
>   a level of indirection

`Int#` is the name for GHC's unboxed Int type. `Int` is simply a wrapper around this type.

```
Prelude> import GHC.Int
Prelude GHC.Int> :info Int
data Int = I# GHC.Prim.Int#     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
```

The hash is simply a naming convention for unboxed types which have no heap representation. You'll need to enable the extension `-XMagicHash` to refer to these names though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too obvious to say but the main difference is that in the first case the constructor will have type

```
T :: Int -> T
```

and in the second case

```
T :: Int# -> T
```

In terms of the runtime representation, there will be no difference (except that I think `UNPACK` is ignored if optimizations are disabled). So in the case of `T {-# UNPACK #-} !Int`, for example, pattern matching `case t of T n -> ...` has to create a new `I#` box for `n` (which hopefully will cancel with another `case` nearby).